# Touchpad tap not working after NVidia driver

Tags: nvidia, mouse, touchpad, cinnamon

I'm running Ubuntu 13.04 with Cinnamon as my Desktop environment. I recently isntalled the NVidia propietary drivers (directly from their webpage) and now, the tap in my touchpad is not working. The touchpad is working because I can use the border to scroll but for some reason the tap is broken. Here's ther esult of my xinput list:

```
$ xinput list
⎡ Virtual core pointer                      id=2    [master pointer  (3)]
⎜   ↳ Virtual core XTEST pointer                id=4    [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ DualPoint Stick                           id=14   [slave  pointer  (2)]
⎜   ↳ AlpsPS/2 ALPS DualPoint TouchPad          id=15   [slave  pointer  (2)]
```

Help is appreciated. Thanks,

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
synclient tapbutton1=1
```

I had the same issue but I don't recall installing any NVIDIA drivers.  Hope this helps.